Where can I find a list of most valuable single patent families in history?
Im looking for instances moreso of pure licensing/enforcement and not of a product manufacturer. Single families and not portfolios. Also if possible organized by domain of the invention. Thank you.
I tried searching and found that the discussion was always around portfolios or talking about revenues of a product manufacturer.
Thanks

No idea, but I would bet a drug patent.
